# The set of all function one-to-one limited by another function is countable?

Tags: real-analysis

So, my question is, if I have the set of all one-to-one function with natural domain and the image natural, limited, for example $ x + 1 $, so my set is countable or not?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you say precisely what you mean by "limited"?

Comment: All functions of this set have this inequality $f(x) \leq x+1$

Comment: Even, if the image only consists of the set {$0,1$}, there are uncountable many functions from $\mathbb N$ to that image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you want a function $f(n)$ such that $n \leftrightarrow f(n)$ is a bijection and $f(n) \le n+1$.  You can represent your functions as sequencse of naturals, where the natural in position $n$ is $f(n)$.  You can break the naturals into pairs $(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),\ldots$.  I will make a set of functions that can be represented by choosing which pairs to reverse.  There is the identity function $1,2,3,4,5\ldots$, the one with all pairs reversed $2,1,4,3,6,5,\ldots$ and many more.  Can you convince yourself that we can interchange any combination of the pairs and meet $f(n) \le n+1?$  Each of these sequences represents a function in your set.  We have $\aleph_0$ binary choices to make, so there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ functions in my set.  My set is a subset of yours.

Comment: Okay so with that argument I can show that my set is a union of countable sets?

Comment: No, you can't.  Take any infinite binary series.  Use a $1$ to say flip a pair and $0$ to say don't flip it.  This shows my set of functions is the size of the continuum